# document.execCommand not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

This is a tough one for me.

Got a conentEditable div with some formating buttons. One of these is a "bold" button:

```
<li data-role="button" data-button-role="bold"><b>B</b></li>
```

In my javascript i got this little peace of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-role='button'][data-button-role='bold']").click(toggleBoltFormat);
});
function toggleBoltFormat() {
    document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
}
```

This things get called (tested with alert()), but the execCommand line is not being executed. So the highlighted text is not getting bold.

Can it be a problem with relativ and absolut position of some parent element of the cE-div?

When putting the docuement.execCommand line in my chromes js-console, it works fine.

Comment: `designMode` might need to be on `document.designMode = 'on;'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something similar like this html's `unselectable="on"` behavior. Created a class called  unselectable and added into `<li>`:

```html
<li data-role="button" data-button-role="bold" class="unselectable"><b>B</b></li>
```

```css
.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: used it with an attribute selctor `*[data-role="button"]` which works fine. But using the attribute in html `unselectable="on"` does nothing, should it?